# How to remove automatic exponential coordinate value (Polystyrene Foam in this case) in tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgf,pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ 
xbar, xmin=0,
xlabel={\textbf{Unit Weight (in $\mathbf{kN/m^3}$)}},
symbolic y coords={%
{Wood (Oak)},
{Wood (Pine)},
{Water},
{Steel},
{Polystyrene Foam},
{Limestone},
{Glass}, 
{Concrete}, 
{Brick},
Aluminium},
ytick=data,
nodes near coords, 
nodes near coords align={horizontal},
ytick=data, ylabel={\textbf{Building/Construction Materials}},width=13.5cm,height=8cm
]
\addplot[xbar,fill=red!60] coordinates {
(27.0,{Aluminium})
(19.3,{Brick})
(24.0,{Concrete})
(24.2,{Glass})
(16.2,{Limestone})
(0.3,{Polystyrene Foam})
(76.8,{Steel})
(9.8,{Water})
(5.0,{Wood (Pine)})
(7.1,{Wood (Oak)})};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Indenting each line by 4 spaces will make your code look the way it does in the typical posts you see. Then it will be more readable.

Comment: After adding `pgfplots` to your packages and `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}`
(i.e., using the latest version), I get something different: http://i.imgur.com/Ge4ivMJ.png What version of `pgfplots` do you use?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Thank you. I was using \pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}. But if the value was 0.03 instead of 0.3, the exponential still exist. Please help me.

Comment: @HarishKumar Could you please provide me a solution to get rid of the the exponential and also to provide the decimal value for 5.0 (whole number)? Thank you.

Comment: @HarishKumar I know. I wrote `1.11`, but meant `1.12`.

Comment: It works perfectly fine @Harish Kumar sir.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Thank you sir for your time and kind help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With version 1.12, I get `0.3`. Hence you may need an update for your `pgfplots` package. To add  zero  to `5`, you may use this:

```
every node near coord/.append style={/pgf/number format/precision=1,
/pgf/number format/fixed,
/pgf/number format/fixed zerofill},
```

in the `axis` options.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}   %% better use this and 1.12 may be your version
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
xbar, xmin=0,
xlabel={\textbf{Unit Weight (in $\mathbf{kN/m^3}$)}},
symbolic y coords={%
{Wood (Oak)},
{Wood (Pine)},
{Water},
{Steel},
{Polystyrene Foam},
{Limestone},
{Glass},
{Concrete},
{Brick},
Aluminium},
ytick=data,
nodes near coords,
every node near coord/.append style={/pgf/number format/precision=1,
/pgf/number format/fixed,
/pgf/number format/fixed zerofill,},
nodes near coords align={horizontal},
ytick=data, ylabel={\textbf{Building/Construction Materials}},width=13.5cm,height=8cm
]
\addplot[xbar,fill=red!60] coordinates {
(27.0,{Aluminium})
(19.3,{Brick})
(24.0,{Concrete})
(24.2,{Glass})
(16.2,{Limestone})
(0.3,{Polystyrene Foam})
(76.8,{Steel})
(9.8,{Water})
(5.0,{Wood (Pine)})
(7.1,{Wood (Oak)})};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you are using `0.03` instead of `0.3` then you have to use `/pgf/number format/precision=2`, otherwise you will get 0.0 instead of 0.03.

Comment: Thank you so much, this answers the entire queries. It works perfectly fine. Thank You.

Comment: Yes Harish Kumar sir, I'll do that but I need to earn 15 reputations to do that. I've earned only 14 and I'll surely do that when I get 15.

Comment: Yes got it. Thanks Harish Kumar sir...! I eventually crossed 15 reputation mark as well. I certainly acknowledge you in my thesis.

Comment: @RameshKannan Thank you Ramesh. Have a nice time. :-)